# How do gradient-based optimization methods deal with outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, gradient-descent

I have seen in many different places that a basic assumption is that the training data and test data follow the same distribution. However, there are references that talk about outliers in the training and/or test data.

I have two questions about these assumptions:

1. If all input data have the same distribution, what does it mean to have outliers?
2. Assuming that there are outliers in the input, how do gradient-based methods deal with them? For example, if the objective function is quadratic and an outlier exists in the training data, it can cause the gradient to move much faster towards a direction which may not be the right direction. I can imagine this problem gets worse when doing stochastic gradient-descent optimization where we make decisions only based on the last training data or in momentum-based methods where the gradient in previous iterations is taken into account.